# Show $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ $x\rightarrow -x$ is bijective

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

> We have a function $$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$
>    $$x\rightarrow -x$$
>
> Show $f$ is bijective.

**One-to-one:** Assume $f(x)=f(y)$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, then $-x=-y$, hence $x=y$. Thus, $f$ is one-to-one function.

**Onto**:Let $y\in\mathbb{R}$. We need to find $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=y$. Since $y\in\mathbb{R}$, let $-x=y\in\mathbb{R}$, so there is a $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=-x$. **Can you check?**

Comment: Have you tried $x=-y$?

Comment: "Assume $f(x)=f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$" should be "for some".

Comment: Not meaning to be rude, but have you given this any thought at all?

Comment: @Arthur Yes, thanks...

Comment: @freakish Let $y\in\mathbb{R}$. We need to find $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=y$. Since $y\in\mathbb{R}$, let $-x=y\in\mathbb{R}$, so there is a $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=-x$. Can you check?

Comment: May you check my last comment?

Comment: $x\rightarrow -x$ is a linear transformation between two finite dimensional real vector spaces. It is injective since $-x=0$ implies $x=0$. Hence it is a linear isomorphism. Hence it is bijective.

Comment: @PozcuKushimotoStreet You are looking for $x$ such that $f(x)=y$. So take $x:=-y$. And calculate: $f(x)=f(-y)=-(-y)=y$. And therefore that particularly chosen $x$ satisfies your condition.

Comment: @Leaning Thanks, but I need set-theoritical proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-to-one is fine.

For onto, take an arbitrary $y\in\Bbb R$. We see that $f(-y)=y$. This shows that $f$ is onto.

Comment: Thanks for answer and comment.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

Since $f$ is decreasing it is injective and since it is continuos it is also surjective.